# Is Amazon.in is certified iPhone dealer in India?

Tags: iphone

Is Amazon.in is certified iPhone dealer in India? Will I get a genuine product from there?

This is the product that I am looking at:

- http://www.amazon.in/Apple-iPhone-5c-Blue-8GB/dp/B00L8WSNMG/ref=sr_1_2?m=A14UQ4H17XUX90&s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1430745395&sr=1-2

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you can see, the manufacturer is Apple.
The seller is Cloudtail and it is fulfilled by Amazon, so Amazon guarantee on the quality of the product.

You're buying a genuine iPhone 5C, if something goes wrong, you can ask a refund or replace because the product is not clear enough or not the same as the advertised one.

You can also check the product review, they've got a positive rating, so everything seems ok.

You can buy Apple product from whenever you want, and later register it for Apple warranty support providing a valid receipt.

Comment: no the seller is "cloudtail" fulfilled by amazon. that is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer in finding official Apple resellers is to browse to:

- https://locate.apple.com

From there, you can select your country in the top right of the page (for me it populates USA as the default, but I probably have lots of US based cookies in Safari and an US based IP address).

In your case, I pretended you were shopping in Chennai and selected iPhone and got these results.

[image]

So, it appears Apple hasn't certified Amazon in India but it's hard to know based on location alone for an internet reseller. In the US, you have to be careful when ordering parts from Amazon since not all are actually sold by Amazon and instead are sold through that market from various third party sellers. You'd want to be sure the refund policies were lenient enough for you to inspect the goods and understand the dispute process/return process if you feel you were mis-shipped or mis-led.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the list of Apple Authorised Resellers for Internet or catalogue sales in India

http://www.apple.com/in/buy/catalogresellers/